# How can we send messages from the main process to renderer process in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm playing with electron for the first time. Trying to create a text editor

In render I'm sending a message to indicated the content has changed and needs saving:

```
document.getElementById('content').onkeyup = e => {
  ipcRenderer.send('SAVE_NEEDED', {
    content: e.target.innerHTML,
    fileDir
  })
}
```

Then `ipcMain` receives it no problem. On the menu I have this:

```
{
  label: 'Save',
  click: _ => {
     saveFile(message)
     // trying:
     // ipcMain.send('SAVED', 'File Saved')
     },
     accelerator: 'cmd+S', // shortcut
}
```

So that the user knows the files has have. But that doesn't seem to work. Is there any other way to do this? **I would have thought "save" would be a pre-created role (sort of)**

Answer (score 84, accepted):

To send a message back to the renderer you would use:

```js
win.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', {'SAVED': 'File Saved'});
```

And receive it like this:

```js
ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', function (evt, message) {
    console.log(message); // Returns: {'SAVED': 'File Saved'}
});
```

Where `asynchronous-message` is simply the channel you're sending it to. It can literally be anything.

[`webContents.send` Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args)

Comment: If you want to send a direct message and doesn't have access to the Event, This works! :)

Comment: If you send the message, like for example right after reloading the window, wrap the message sending in `win.webContents.once('did-finish-load', () => { ... })`

Comment: I tried this, but got the EventEmitter warning about a possible memory leak. Is there any way to clean up the previous events before emitting a new event?

Comment: @Yamo93 I'm not exactly sure what you mean, can you post a new question with all the details?

Comment: @Joshua I posted this question now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956184/memory-leak-when-emitting-an-event-after-menu-click-in-electron-app

Comment: Recomend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807459/how-to-use-preload-js-properly-in-electron/69917666#69917666) by @abel-callejo, where ipcRenderer need not be exposed to renderer.

Comment: I have same problem , I have 3 files main.js , app.js and savinimages.js. Main Application Running on main.js and html file included. app.js running server and receiving data. I am able to Communicate between main.js and app.js. I want to open new window based on button click(new window having another html file and savingimages.js included in html file) and I want to show {"apple" : "mango"} value. How to communicate main.js to saveimages.js or app.js to savingimages.js

Answer (score 21):

alternatively - when you want to **respond** to an event received from renderer process you can do something like this:

```
     ipcMain.on("eventFromRenderer", (event) => {
          event.sender.send("eventFromMain", someReply);
     }
```

Source: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Comment: But this does NOT work if you want the MainProcess to initiate the first message by sending the first message to the Renderer...

Comment: This works for the following flow: **Renderer** › **Main** › **Renderer**. Although the question is about the following flow: **Main** › **Renderer**

Answer (score 17):

Here is what I tinkered with (using the new way of doing with `contextBridge`), my use was simply to have a menuItem call a navigation event in my React code:

```
// preload.js

const exposedAPI = {
  // `(customData: string) => void` is just the typing here
  onMenuNav: (cb: (customData: string) => void) => {
    // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` (note: Not sure about that, I partly pasted it from somewhere)
    // Note: The first argument is always event, but you can have as many arguments as you like, one is enough for me.
    ipcRenderer.on('your-event', (event, customData) => cb(customData));
  }
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", exposedAPI);
```

```
// typing for curious peoples
onMenuNav(cb: ((customData: string) => void)): void;
```

```
// renderer.tsx
// Call it in the renderer process, in my case it is called once at the end of renderer.tsx.

window.electron.onMenuNav(customData => {
  console.log(customData); // 'something'
});
```

```
// in main process

const customData = 'something';
mainWindow.webContents.send('your-event', customData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I found new good solution;

```
// on main process index.js
ipcMain.on('event-name', (event, data) => {
    const value = 'return value';
    event.reply(data.waitingEventName, value);
});

// on render frame index.html
const send =(callback)=>{
    const waitingEventName = 'event-name-reply';
    ipcRenderer.once(waitingEventName, (event, data) => {
        callback(data);
    });
    ipcRenderer.send('event-name', {waitingEventName});
};
send((value)=>{
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but I don't think it's well explained. Correct me if I'm wrong, I think it's essentially long-polling: you are sending a message to Main, that sticks around (it's async after all). When Main needs to send a message to Renderer, it replies to the previous message that was hanging around there, and then Renderer, upon receiving the reply, should reply a new message that will lie waiting with Main until Main wants to send a message back to Renderer. If that's right, then the code should better reflect that. I'm also not sure if there can be some sort of time-out issue

Answer (score 1):

From @raksa answer

You can send a request to main and get a response, rather than sending a response that might not be delivered.

Use this sample

```
//render process
ipcRenderer.send('hello', ['one', 'two', 'three']);

ipcRenderer.once('nice', (e, data) => {
  console.log(data); //['one','two','three']
}) 

//main process
  ipcMain.on('hello', (e, data) => {
    e.reply('nice', data)
  })
```

Comment: Little off-topic, but we are supposed to use preload approach by new standards, or am I missing something? (since this approach is 2 months old, but ignores preload..)