# window.webContents.send() causes memory leak

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm experiencing an issue in Electron where `window.webContents.send()` behaves as expected on the first execution, but after I call it again the function runs twice, then three times, etc.

Here's a stripped back example of one of the menubar functions I'm using to tell the renderer to package data for saving.

**Main.js**

```
   {
      label: 'Save',
      click() {
         window.webContents.send('myChannel', myArgs); 
      }
   }
```

**Renderer.js**

```
   ipcRenderer.once('myChannel', (evt, myArgs) => {
      // package data for saving
   });
```

My understanding is that Electron is creating a new event handler each time I click save in the menubar. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to dispose the event handler in the electron docs.

Here's a link to a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956184/memory-leak-when-emitting-an-event-after-menu-click-in-electron-app). The solution isn't of much help to me, as I need these functions to only be run when they're called from the menubar, not when the app first launches.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you listening using `once` if you're going to call the event more than one time?

Comment: @Autumn this was an attempt to stop the memory leak. I experienced the same behavior when using `.on()` as well :/