# Updating the renderer with the results of an executed command from the main

Tags: node.js, electron, stdout, stderr

Electron can execute low-level commands through the following NodeJS APIs:

- [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)
- [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options)
- [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)
- [`spawnSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options)

These APIs can only be executed on the **Main** process. Which means they won't work on the **Preload** and **Renderer** processes.

Given that you have the tier of processes:
**Main** › **Preload** › **Renderer**

How can the **Renderer** process capture the `stdout` and `stderr` messages happening on the **Main** process, line per line as they happen?

Basically, how to update the **Renderer** process with the outputs/progress happening from the **Main** process while having in mind you have to expose some APIs via the **Preload**?

Comment: What about [`ipcRenderer.sendSync`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-args) and [`ipcMain,on`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener) ? Both can be used to execute a command on `main` and send the output synchronously to `renderer`

Comment: @cachique Well, [`ipcMain.on()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener) only listens and doesn't send while [`ipcRenderer.sendSync()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-args) only sends and doesn't listen.

It seem to be the opposite of this topic. This topic is about sending a message from the **Main** to **Renderer**. Not the other way around.

Comment: don't you just want to grab the renderer's window and do `window.webContents.send("message", data);` and intercept it in the renderer via `ipcRenderer.on`?

Comment: I was just about to comment that @pushkin

Comment: As you said in your post, execution can only happen in `main`. The thing I think it matters is who starts the action. If it is the `renderer` then you use `ipcRenderer`. If it is `main` then you use `webContents`. I can think of writing a line at a time from a text file or update the total records proccesed of a database so long as examples of your question. Both of them can be started either on `renderer` or in `main`. I did both things on apps as `renderer`'s actions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we send messages main process to renderer process in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124675/how-can-we-send-messages-main-process-to-renderer-process-in-electron)

Comment: Partly, this topic would easily look like a duplicate. However, the link you are suggesting only deals with **Main** and **Renderer**, what I am after here is how to make it work with using **Preload** too. This is a `v13.*` and onwards. Do you think that makes a difference?

Comment: not really. You can use ipcRenderer the same in preload.